# Count number of nodes in subtree

Tags: node.js, tree, subtree

I have a tree and I have to return a copy of the tree with each node set with the number of nodes in the left subtree and the right subtree

[image]

this is the tree structure

[image]

izq means left and der means right

Comment: Your question does not show the minimal understanding of the problem and does not show you effort in solving it, so the question can be marked as off-topic or down-voted. Do not be surprised. If you seek for help, show your code.

Comment: The code in your pic is not in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework. But here's a tip:

Check depth first recursion.

Comment: Another tip: Unlike in air travel, you should take care of your kids BEFORE yourself.